# How to get group posts and their comments from Workplace Graph API in a single request?

Tags: api, facebook-workplace

I know I can get all the posts in a group using the Graph API endpoint `/group-id/feed`.  And I know I can get all the comments of a single post too. But I want to know if it's possible to get the comments of each posts in a group in a single request.

Ideally, I would want something like "get the latest 10 posts of a group with their comments" in a single request.

Couldn't find anything in the docs so it's probably not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the fields parameter

/group-id/feed?fields=message,comments

in this way you are able to retrieve the message of the post and all the comments related to it

Comment: Amazing. I was using some fields but I guess I missed that one. Thanks.
EDIT: Actually it's not listed in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/post - How did you find it?

Comment: Because the Workplace graph API are a subset of the Facebook ones and I tryed if the Facebook feature worked also in Workplace

Comment: This works but doesnt get me the replies to the comments though.. Is there a way to get replies as well?